# Custom hover text, singular/plural (plotly.js)

Tags: plotly

I'm building a scatter graph.

My X axis represents dates, and Y axis represents the number of responses given.

When mouse hovering, I'd like to show either:

- 1 response
  OR
- N responses

I suppose it is something to do with custom hovering, but can't see how to do it with the `hoverinfo` property of the trace or Y-axis.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `text` attribute in the trace.

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/n54k9zzj/

```
var data =
[
  {x: "2015-05-01", y: 5},
  {x: "2015-05-02", y: 10},
  {x: "2015-05-03", y: 0},
  {x: "2015-05-04", y: 1}
];

var x = [];
var y = [];
var text = [];
data.forEach(function(item, index)
{
  x.push(item.x);
  y.push(item.y);
  if (item.y == 0)
  {
    text.push("No responses");
  }
  else if (item.y == 1)
  {
    text.push("1 reponse");
  }
  else
  {
    text.push(item.y + " responses");
  }
});

var trace = 
{
  x: x,
  y: y,
  text: text,
  hoverinfo: "text",
  mode: "markers",
  name: "Responses"
}

var yaxis = 
{
    title: "Responses"
}

var xaxis = 
{
    type: "date"
}

var layout = 
{
  xaxis: xaxis,
  yaxis: yaxis
}

Plotly.plot
(
  "graph",
  [trace],
  layout
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want custom text added , then try something like this :

```
var myText = "Namaste" ;

var trace = {
    x: [1,2,3],
    y: [4,5,6],
    z: [7,8,9],
    text: ["A","B","C"],
    hovertemplate: ' x: %{x}<br> y: %{y}<br> z: %{z}<br> Placement:%{text}<br> myText: ' + myText,
    mode: 'markers' ,
    type: 'scatter3d' ,
    marker: {
        size:3,
        color: 'rgb(112, 32, 130)'
    }
};
```

Note : Property "text", "hovertemplate" plays important role in adding your own custom text .

Comment: Note that you can use the keyword `%{text}` and `%{customdata}` in `hovertemplate` if you need more custom texts